# In which format is information stored in view state?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I want to know in which format information is stored in view state, as it is quite useful for storing information during multiple postbacks.

Answer (score 2):

**View state** is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to preserve page and control values between round trips. When the HTML markup for the page is rendered, the current state of the page and values that must be retained during postback are **serialized into base64-encoded strings**. This information is then put into the view state hidden field or fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE"
 value="dDwxNDg5OTk5MzM7Oz7DblWpxMjE3ATl4Jx621QnCmJ2VQ==" />
```

Comment: But, you shouldn't rely on it being so, as microsoft do not guarantee that this will always be the format.

Comment: @PranayRana is there any other method rather than base64-encoded strings to store the view state value on it ?